# Pushing the sub-menu items together... Cant find the CSS?

Tags: css

No idea why but I cant find the CSS to bring my submenu items together on the navigation. I am attempting to make the sub-menu navigation horizontal as well but they are really stretched out. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

http://palmcasualpvc.com/cushion-sets

Comment: Can you paste some of your HTML and CSS here? There is little to go on to help you.

Comment: Stuff like this is pretty easy to figure out once you have a decent working knowledge of the included developer tools. You can just "inspect element" then see where any margin/padding/width is applied via your css, and even manipulate it on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submenu spacing is being inherited by the main menu styling. There is a `margin-right` rule causing this. You can start with this:

```
.main-navigation li {
  margin: 0;
}
```

There is also a width being set to the items in the submenu. Try this:

```
.main-navigation li ul li a {
  width: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS class `.main-navigation ul ul` remove `width: 900px` and add `background-color: Yellow;` to `.main-navigation li li`